# Flutter: Build ios error : ld: 13 duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64

Tags: ios, flutter

After some trouble to add Geolocator plugin and couldn't work. I removed Geolocator from pubspec.yaml but now the project couldnt build for ios.
I have tried for 2 days without success including:

1. Change Flutter channel
2. Flutter upgrade
3. Pod deintegrate
4. Delete the xcode project files
5. added 'config.build_settings['SWIFT_VERSION'] = '4.1'
6. and many more I cant remember now.

   duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_MDMPasscodeCache._localAuthenticationInfo in:
   /Volumes/flutter/ios/Pods/GoogleMobileVision/Detector/Frameworks/GoogleMobileVision.framework/GoogleMobileVision(MDMPasscodeCache_f189776e75765630b82721fafea64052.o)
   /Volumes/flutter/ios/Pods/GoogleSignIn/Frameworks/GoogleSignIn.framework/GoogleSignIn(MDMPasscodeCache_42de90102bb6814d03833694aafcc99d.o)
   duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_MDMPasscodeCache._keychainInfo in:
   /Volumes/flutter/ios/Pods/GoogleMobileVision/Detector/Frameworks/GoogleMobileVision.framework/GoogleMobileVision(MDMPasscodeCache_f189776e75765630b82721fafea64052.o)
   /Volumes/flutter/ios/Pods/GoogleSignIn/Frameworks/GoogleSignIn.framework/GoogleSignIn(MDMPasscodeCache_42de90102bb6814d03833694aafcc99d.o)
   duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_MDMPasscodeCache._hasLocalAuthentication in:
   /Volumes/flutter/ios/Pods/GoogleMobileVision/Detector/Frameworks/GoogleMobileVision.framework/GoogleMobileVision(MDMPasscodeCache_f189776e75765630b82721fafea64052.o)
   /Volumes/flutter/ios/Pods/GoogleSignIn/Frameworks/GoogleSignIn.framework/GoogleSignIn(MDMPasscodeCache_42de90102bb6814d03833694aafcc99d.o)
   duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_MDMPasscodeCache._hasKeychain in:
   /Volumes/flutter/ios/Pods/GoogleMobileVision/Detector/Frameworks/GoogleMobileVision.framework/GoogleMobileVision(MDMPasscodeCache_f189776e75765630b82721fafea64052.o)
   /Volumes/flutter/ios/Pods/GoogleSignIn/Frameworks/GoogleSignIn.framework/GoogleSignIn(MDMPasscodeCache_42de90102bb6814d03833694aafcc99d.o)
   duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_MDMPasscodeCache._cachedState in:
   /Volumes/flutter/ios/Pods/GoogleMobileVision/Detector/Frameworks/GoogleMobileVision.framework/GoogleMobileVision(MDMPasscodeCache_f189776e75765630b82721fafea64052.o)
   /Volumes/flutter/ios/Pods/GoogleSignIn/Frameworks/GoogleSignIn.framework/GoogleSignIn(MDMPasscodeCache_42de90102bb6814d03833694aafcc99d.o)
   duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_MDMPasscodeCache._keychainExpireTime in:
   /Volumes/flutter/ios/Pods/GoogleMobileVision/Detector/Frameworks/GoogleMobileVision.framework/GoogleMobileVision(MDMPasscodeCache_f189776e75765630b82721fafea64052.o)
   /Volumes/flutter/ios/Pods/GoogleSignIn/Frameworks/GoogleSignIn.framework/GoogleSignIn(MDMPasscodeCache_42de90102bb6814d03833694aafcc99d.o)
   duplicate symbol _OBJC_CLASS_$_MDMPasscodeCache in:
   /Volumes/flutter/ios/Pods/GoogleMobileVision/Detector/Frameworks/GoogleMobileVision.framework/GoogleMobileVision(MDMPasscodeCache_f189776e75765630b82721fafea64052.o)
   /Volumes/flutter/ios/Pods/GoogleSignIn/Frameworks/GoogleSignIn.framework/GoogleSignIn(MDMPasscodeCache_42de90102bb6814d03833694aafcc99d.o)
   duplicate symbol _OBJC_METACLASS_$_MDMPasscodeCache in:
   /Volumes/flutter/ios/Pods/GoogleMobileVision/Detector/Frameworks/GoogleMobileVision.framework/GoogleMobileVision(MDMPasscodeCache_f189776e75765630b82721fafea64052.o)
   /Volumes/flutter/ios/Pods/GoogleSignIn/Frameworks/GoogleSignIn.framework/GoogleSignIn(MDMPasscodeCache_42de90102bb6814d03833694aafcc99d.o)
   duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_MDMPasscodeCache._hasEnteredBackground in:
   /Volumes/flutter/ios/Pods/GoogleMobileVision/Detector/Frameworks/GoogleMobileVision.framework/GoogleMobileVision(MDMPasscodeCache_f189776e75765630b82721fafea64052.o)
   /Volumes/flutter/ios/Pods/GoogleSignIn/Frameworks/GoogleSignIn.framework/GoogleSignIn(MDMPasscodeCache_42de90102bb6814d03833694aafcc99d.o)
   duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_MDMPasscodeState._status in:
   /Volumes/flutter/ios/Pods/GoogleMobileVision/Detector/Frameworks/GoogleMobileVision.framework/GoogleMobileVision(MDMPasscodeState_d2697588db599ad1e82d46f342216cee.o)
   /Volumes/flutter/ios/Pods/GoogleSignIn/Frameworks/GoogleSignIn.framework/GoogleSignIn(MDMPasscodeState_adbe96d99863168799049cc0f0164c6d.o)
   duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_MDMPasscodeState._info in:
   /Volumes/flutter/ios/Pods/GoogleMobileVision/Detector/Frameworks/GoogleMobileVision.framework/GoogleMobileVision(MDMPasscodeState_d2697588db599ad1e82d46f342216cee.o)
   /Volumes/flutter/ios/Pods/GoogleSignIn/Frameworks/GoogleSignIn.framework/GoogleSignIn(MDMPasscodeState_adbe96d99863168799049cc0f0164c6d.o)
   duplicate symbol _OBJC_CLASS_$_MDMPasscodeState in:
   /Volumes/flutter/ios/Pods/GoogleMobileVision/Detector/Frameworks/GoogleMobileVision.framework/GoogleMobileVision(MDMPasscodeState_d2697588db599ad1e82d46f342216cee.o)
   /Volumes/flutter/ios/Pods/GoogleSignIn/Frameworks/GoogleSignIn.framework/GoogleSignIn(MDMPasscodeState_adbe96d99863168799049cc0f0164c6d.o)
   duplicate symbol _OBJC_METACLASS_$_MDMPasscodeState in:
   /Volumes/flutter/ios/Pods/GoogleMobileVision/Detector/Frameworks/GoogleMobileVision.framework/GoogleMobileVision(MDMPasscodeState_d2697588db599ad1e82d46f342216cee.o)
   /Volumes/flutter/ios/Pods/GoogleSignIn/Frameworks/GoogleSignIn.framework/GoogleSignIn(MDMPasscodeState_adbe96d99863168799049cc0f0164c6d.o)
   ld: 13 duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64
   clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Now, I am at loss on how to resolve this.

UPDATE:
Now I have new errors after deleting and reinstalling CocoaPods:

Analyzing dependencies
Fetching podspec for `Flutter` from `.symlinks/flutter/ios`
Fetching podspec for `cloud_firestore` from `.symlinks/plugins/cloud_firestore/ios`
Fetching podspec for `connectivity` from `.symlinks/plugins/connectivity/ios`
Fetching podspec for `firebase_admob` from `.symlinks/plugins/firebase_admob/ios`
Fetching podspec for `firebase_analytics` from `.symlinks/plugins/firebase_analytics/ios`
Fetching podspec for `firebase_auth` from `.symlinks/plugins/firebase_auth/ios`
Fetching podspec for `firebase_core` from `.symlinks/plugins/firebase_core/ios`
Fetching podspec for `firebase_messaging` from `.symlinks/plugins/firebase_messaging/ios`
Fetching podspec for `firebase_storage` from `.symlinks/plugins/firebase_storage/ios`
Fetching podspec for `flutter_native_image` from `.symlinks/plugins/flutter_native_image/ios`
Fetching podspec for `google_sign_in` from `.symlinks/plugins/google_sign_in/ios`
Fetching podspec for `image_picker` from `.symlinks/plugins/image_picker/ios`
Fetching podspec for `native_device_orientation` from `.symlinks/plugins/native_device_orientation/ios`
Fetching podspec for `package_info` from `.symlinks/plugins/package_info/ios`
Fetching podspec for `path_provider` from `.symlinks/plugins/path_provider/ios`
Fetching podspec for `qr_mobile_vision` from `.symlinks/plugins/qr_mobile_vision/ios`
Fetching podspec for `share` from `.symlinks/plugins/share/ios`
Fetching podspec for `url_launcher` from `.symlinks/plugins/url_launcher/ios`
[!] CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "Firebase/AdMob":
  In Podfile:
    firebase_admob (from `.symlinks/plugins/firebase_admob/ios`) was resolved to 0.0.1, which depends on
      Firebase/AdMob

Specs satisfying the `Firebase/AdMob` dependency were found, but they required a higher minimum deployment target.
CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "GoogleUtilities/AppDelegateSwizzler":
  In Podfile:
    firebase_admob (from `.symlinks/plugins/firebase_admob/ios`) was resolved to 0.0.1, which depends on
      Firebase/AdMob was resolved to 5.8.0, which depends on
        Firebase/Core (= 5.8.0) was resolved to 5.8.0, which depends on
          FirebaseAnalytics (= 5.1.2) was resolved to 5.1.2, which depends on
            GoogleUtilities/AppDelegateSwizzler (~> 5.2.0)

Specs satisfying the `GoogleUtilities/AppDelegateSwizzler (~> 5.2.0)` dependency were found, but they required a higher minimum deployment target.
CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "gRPC-Core":
  In Podfile:
    cloud_firestore (from `.symlinks/plugins/cloud_firestore/ios`) was resolved to 0.0.1, which depends on
      Firebase/Firestore was resolved to 5.8.0, which depends on
        FirebaseFirestore (= 0.13.3) was resolved to 0.13.3, which depends on
          gRPC-C++ (~> 0.0.3) was resolved to 0.0.3, which depends on
            gRPC-C++/Implementation (= 0.0.3) was resolved to 0.0.3, which depends on
              gRPC-Core (= 1.14.0)

```
cloud_firestore (from `.symlinks/plugins/cloud_firestore/ios`) was resolved to 0.0.1, which depends on
  Firebase/Firestore was resolved to 5.8.0, which depends on
    FirebaseFirestore (= 0.13.3) was resolved to 0.13.3, which depends on
      gRPC-ProtoRPC (~> 1.0) was resolved to 1.14.1, which depends on
        gRPC-ProtoRPC/Main (= 1.14.1) was resolved to 1.14.1, which depends on
          gRPC (= 1.14.1) was resolved to 1.14.1, which depends on
            gRPC/Main (= 1.14.1) was resolved to 1.14.1, which depends on
              gRPC-Core (= 1.14.1)
```

Comment: Now I have new errors after deleting and reinstalling CocoaPods:

Comment: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/20685#issuecomment-421511890  might help